# I can be grey, but also white

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Hello, who are you?
>   You are touching me right now, aren't you?
>   I can be grey, but also white
>   I can be quite heavy, but also light
>   Some people hate and are scared by me
>   but I can cook like a chef, trust me!
>   If people are taking a picture, I hope they wouldn't mind
>   because I am going to come, but I will disappointed on what I'll find
>   The word you have to find is the same,
>   But I can recognized in many things, I'm not to blame!

I know this riddle is not the best; it's my second one. Anyway I hope you enjoyed it!

Comment: Mine is just plain black

Comment: @nl-x So what is it? :P

Comment: I can be grey, but also white -> Gandalf

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Are you a

> mouse?

You are touching me right now, aren't you?

> It's true, I was touching my computer mouse as I read the clue.

I can be grey, but also white

> Mice can be many colors, most commonly grey or white.

I can be quite heavy, but also light

> Not sure how heavy a mouse can be, but they can definitely be light. I guess gaming computer mice can be quite hefty.

Some people hate and are scared by me

> musophobia

but I can cook like a chef, trust me!

> Ratatouille!

If people are taking a picture, I hope they wouldn't mind
because I am going to come, but I will disappointed on what I'll find

> People say 'Cheese' during photos, and when the mouse comes to steal said cheese, he will be disappointed to find none.

Comment: +1 Since this is (probably) what OP intended, but darn - I die a little inside every time someone misidentifies Remy's genus. It's literally in the title of the movie....

Comment: Wow, Great answer. What about the last clue though?

Comment: @Mithrandir I thought "But I can be recognized in many things, I'm not to blame" was a clue. Is it not?

Comment: @Areeb Ah. You're right. :P /whacks head

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for!

Comment: It can be recognized in many things because, well, How can I answer without spoil the answer?

Comment: That's what I thought too! +1